# Instrumentation test doesn't match view ids from hierarchy

Tags: android, android-espresso, android-instrumentation

In short, I'm trying to match view with ID like `R.id.signCheckbox` using Espresso. When I try to match that view I will get NoMatchingView exception when it's clear that view is present.

After some debugging, I've found out that inside my test class when I eval `R.id.signCheckbox` I'll get ID: `-1000984`. Inside `cause` of the `NoMatchingViewException` you can actually read whole view hierarchy in some format. There I've found that checkbox has different ID `2131362821`. I've read the project `R.java` and it's also assigning `2131362821` to `R.id.signCheckbox`.

So when I match `withId(2131362821)` it's actually working. Why it's not working with `R.id.signCheckbox` and where that `-1000984` id comes from?

Comment: Can you make sure your `import com.yourapp.pkg.R;` **IS** the one you're importing/want to import? R.java file is static and can't change id willy-nilly AFAIK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the good old Invalidate/Restart/Clean/Rebuild fixed the problem.

The IDs are still negative (like -1000984) not matching the R.java IDs, but Espresso will successfully match the views.